# Network projector adapter for existing projector

Tags: untagged

Vista introduced a new capability for supporting network projectors, eliminating the need to connecting via a cable to the projector. Does anyone make adapters that can add support for this to existing projectors? I've found a couple of wireless projector adapters (from Plextor and Infocus) but they seem to require custom software on the projecting computer rather than using the standard Windows functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found one either. From what I understand, to do this the adapter would need to run Windows CE 6.0, then do an RDP session to the Vista computer.

As an added tease, Microsoft even shows a picture of one in their [Windows Network Projector Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa934598.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What Microsoft is refferencing is the "potential" to develop a prodoct that can replicate laptop screens on a projector using their RDP software.   Of course, what couldn't you do with a computer with programming skills and unlimited time and patience for an OS that is loaded with a never ending stream of security vulnerabilities.

If you are interested in a product like this, then check out the RVW 200 Remote Viewer - Wireless Network VGA Adapter.   The Remote Viewer is a turnkey hardware and software soluion built on an embedded linux operating system.   All of the software is served up through a browser interface.

Here's how it works, the Remote Viewer is connected to the projector VGA and to the LAN.   You walk into the conference room with your wireless laptop, open your browser and type in the IP address of the Remote viewer (or create a shortcut).   A web page opens up,you click "connect" and your laptop displays on the projector.   This is perfect when you have multiple people in the conference room for a meeting and need to switch from one person to the next without fumbling with wires, plugs and adapters.   The Remote viewer is loaded extra features like the ability to have a hosted session where the "host" controls which laptop is displaying on the projector, again through a browser interface.   The Remote Viewer even functions as a network media player that can play video files and pictures from its HDD through a playlist functionality; entertain and educate the folks before the meeting or just display the corporate logo.

You can buy them and even view a video demonstration at ethernetav.com.

Comment: "unlimited time and patience for an OS that is loaded with a never ending stream of security vulnerabilities" - these sorts of comments are not helpful, at all, in any way, and should be avoided. I see you're also spruking your own product, which means that you're slightly less than un-biased.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Iogear DVI NetStation](http://www.iogear.com/product/GDIP201/) to connect over a LAN to a 42" 1080p monitor.

Connect the NetStation to the projector, and install the included app on your PC to either duplicate your laptop display to the projector; or even use the projector as a secondary display. This is a nice technique because you can hide you primary desktop from the other members of the meeting.

This is NOT very good for live video though.  The technology is called [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/).